# Missing Excel Library Causing Reference Errors For User Who Don't Need/Use It

Tags: excel, vba, reference, add-in

Okay, I have added a third party add-in that takes signatures.  The user/computer in question that does the signatures has the add-in installed.  Works fine.

There are other users that utilize the same exact spreadsheet and run other VBA scripts that are in this spreadsheet. The problem is that these computers are getting reference errors because they are missing the add-in/library reference that the signature user has, even though the scripts they are using have nothing to do with the added library.

I do have two solutions that should work, but I'm asking you if there might be a simple fix for this.

A. Create a second spreadsheet for the signature user/computer to pull the needed data from the first spreadsheet, so the first spreadsheet won't require the add-in.

B. Install the plug-in on every computer that might utilize the sheet.  Not terribly fond of this option really, because that might never end.

Is there any other way around this beside A and B?

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be Option A. 2 separate files, each file with the macros needed. Elegant and profesional solution would be deactivating the reference to that add-in, and then correct all the code related to that add-in, using late binding, and using numbers as arguments. Don't know how long is your code, and how urgent is this, so I strongly recommend Option A.

Comment: Yep Option A by a mile

Answer (score 1):

There may be is an option C where you can have everything in one Workbook. You could try if Late Binding could work.: http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2018/09/vba-referencing-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/